# different height grid system css

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm new to html&css, I'm trying to set the following grid system:
[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZR0y.png)

look like this:
[desired solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5rBP.png)

My html code consists of 2 main divs (for each 'row'), each one contains 2 divs (logo + notes, nav + content)
I've used display: inline-block in each div, but still can't figure out how to place the blue box directly under the yellow one?
I prefer a solution without jquery plugins, the simplest solution there is
thanks

Code:

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.notes {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 69%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 69%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="notes">
    Notes
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="nav">
    Nav
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Just use one row instead of two.

Comment: This likely isn't possible with just CSS. Items in a new row won't shift up to take up the available space. There is a way to do it if you make columns instead of rows http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/ or you can use the masonry plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: We can only help edit your code. We cannot do this without you posting your code, whether in an external source. eg. JS Fiddle or directly into your question.

Comment: @MichaelCoker code's up here now :)

Comment: @SankarshMakam The code is up here now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-arrange the markup and make 2 columns.

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.logo {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.notes {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;  
}
.main {
  margin-left: 30%;
}
.nav {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    Nav
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="notes">
    Notes
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked up the css-masonry for multi-column as you said, it appears that it doesn't suit the case of different width columns. However this solution looks very well

Comment: @user5618793 no problem. The logo and nav should go in a header together anyways :) If you wanted to be more semantic, you should use `<header>`, `<nav>`, `<aside>` (notes), and `<main>` (content).

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a great way of doing it but this method works. Here are the change, which I have made for you `.content`:

```
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(30% + 7px);
  width: calc(69% - 10px);
```

Here is the final code:

```css
.header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.notes {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 69%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(69% - 10px);
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(30% + 7px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
  <div class="notes">
    Notes
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="nav">
    Nav
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I still cannot upvote.. but this solution works also, thank you!